# Create a patch including specific files in git

Tags: git, file, patch

Let's say that I am 7 commits ahead of the origin/master repo. I would like to create a patch that includes in the patch specific files that were changed, not all the files. Or equivalent exclude specific files from the patch that were changed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can create a patch file by restricting the output of `git diff` by listing paths at the end of the command (after a `--` to avoid any potential clashes between path names and branch names).

For example, you could do the following:

```
git diff origin/master HEAD -- app/models/region.rb doc/ > changes.patch
```

Above commands generate a patch that shows only the differences for a particular file: `region.rb` and a particular directory : `doc` when compared to `origin/master`

Then you can apply the patch using

```
patch -p1 < changes.patch
```

The `-p1` tells patch to strip the `a/` and `b/` in the paths in the patch

Comment: If you're like me and you got here but didn't know how to use the `patch` command (I don't know why you would, but I didn't, so...), you can apply the patch using `patch -p1 < changes.patch` (the `-p1` tells patch to strip the `a/` and `b/` in the paths in the patch)

Comment: @DaisySophiaHollman thanks to your very usefull comment, I have include it in the answer

Answer (score 37):

You can include files in the patches with:

```
git format-patch <rev> <files...>
```

Example

```
git format-patch HEAD^^^ Makefile
```

Will give you three files 0001-[commit] ... 0003-[commit] only containing the Makefile.

Comment: Does this really work? format-patch documentation doesn't say that you can give specific files as parameters.

Comment: It worked for me, even though I haven't found any reference of that feature in the docs.

Comment: I also haven't been able to find documentation of this feature. Was hoping to better understand the options for use in a script!

Comment: In the synopsis of the git-format-patch command, it does show `[<common diff options>]` as an argument. So I think most options for git-diff work for git-format-patch.

Comment: What does the `HEAD^^^` syntax mean? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection The carets mean "ancestor of" -- so this would point at the revision that is the parent of the parent of the parent of HEAD.