# Git: Create a patch from a list of certain files

Tags: git, git-diff, git-patch

I want to create a patch from a list of files. For example I have 10 commits which modify 4 files. I want to create a patch that includes changes of 3 of those 4 files during those 10 commits. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939952/create-a-patch-including-specific-files-in-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
git format-patch -10 -- file1.txt -- file2.txt -- file3.txt
```